# How to find whether phone is in sleep/idle mode for Android

Tags: android

How to find whether phone is in sleep/idle mode for Android?

My problem is I am able to wake up the phone from sleepmode by using alarm manager

But when the phone is not sleep mode and at the same instant if Alarm manager is used to wake the phone..android force closes the App..

whether there is anyway to find whether the Phone is in sleep or idle mode?(Black screen)

**Update:**

My requirement:

When the phone is in sleep mode ---> Intent should be launched from the service
When the phone is not in sleep mode --> The same Intent should be launched from the service

None of the solutions below worked perfectly so here is my little tweak which worked perfectly :):)

```
  //Pending intent for my alarm manager 
  Intent intentaa=new Intent(this,MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentaa, 0);

  //Intent to be launched where MyIntent is the intent
  Intent intenta = new Intent();
  intenta.setClass(this, MyIntent.class);
  intenta.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  //Real code
  try
  {
   startActivity(intenta); 

  }catch(Exception E)
  {

      AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
      pendingIntent);
      startActivity(intenta); 

   }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can check if the screen is turned off by calling [isScreenOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isScreenOn%28%29) method.

Note:This only can be used for 2.1 and above..

Comment: PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
       
 boolean isScreenOn = ((Object) pm).isScreenOn();


I get a error message or isScreenOn methofd for adding a cast

Comment: When I use the isScreenon code given over there..I am getting this error

"Add cast to pm" and when I add cast I am again getting the same error

Comment: Which version of the sdk are you using. It defined for api level >= level 7

Comment: So in this case you'll have to use MByD's solution

Comment: `boolean isScreenOn = ((Object) pm).isScreenOn();` what on earth are you trying to do ?

Comment: `isScreenOn` deprecated at API 20, use `isInteractive()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

`isScreenOn` method returns only if the screen is on or off. It does not indicate the sleepy mode, because Android sleep mode is not same as Android screen off mode. In Android, sleep mode might come within milliseconds (depending on wakelocks) after screen off (idle mode) - but that's not guaranteed  (referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120185/android-sleep-standby-mode)).

I think you can try using `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`,`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` comparison.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [isInteractive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isInteractive())

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
  return pm.isInteractive();
} else {
  return pm.isScreenOn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure thats what you want, but you can use [Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) to determine. see [here an example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/).

Comment: Your solution works fine except when the app is installed after ACTION_SCREEN_OFF is sent - e.g. when the app is installed with screen turned off.