# How to find if phone is in standby mode? (Screen is off, power button pressed)

Tags: android, screen, state

As title says, i need to get this information regarding the screen state.

I think stanby is the correct state i mean, that is when you press the power button and the screen turn off completely.

But how to detect this?

Tnx in advance for your help.

SOLVED:

I managed to solve the problem i was having: the code was right, but the thread was stopping executing when in stanby mode; that's because i was having the wrong feeling that the code was wrong.
Solved simply by using a wake lock, that ensure the cpu will be active even when in stanby mode:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
 wl.acquire();
   ..CPU will stay on during this section..
 wl.release();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691727/how-to-find-whether-phone-is-in-sleep-idle-mode-for-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
```

Comment: Tnx for response.. i've already tried this, but it seems to work only when the device is connected to the pc through the usb cable!
There's no other way?