# Can you programmatically check to determine if your android device is in deep sleep mode?

Tags: android, locking, wifi, sleep

Can you programmatically check to determine if your android device is in deep sleep mode?

Reason being, if it is, you may obtain a wake lock or a wifi lock... however, is it is not, you wouldn't want to obtain a wifi lock if it is not necessary.  Since, I also have a delay created when a wifi lock is obtained in order to allow the device time to connect to the network.  If it is not needed, I do not want to get the wifi lock and add a delay.

Comment: May this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691727/how-to-find-whether-phone-is-in-sleep-idle-mode-for-android

Answer (score 0):

I got a suggestion for you,
Register to screen off  and on, when screen off take a one minute timer, if screen on cancel it, when you got to end of timer do your locks, till screen on again.