# Is there an Android API to identify whether the phone is on idle state

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on custom setting creation, in this scenario i want to create dim screen functionality, it is 70 % completed but i m stuck in one point , for the solution of  this i want to know android idle state; means if user is not using phone or tablet for a particualar time then phone goes in idle state during  this time which android method gets call please let me know

For example when user touch screen then  public void `onUserInteraction()` gets called same as which method call when device goes in idle state.

Comment: A similar question has been asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691727/how-to-find-whether-phone-is-in-sleep-idle-mode-for-android).