# how to identify the mobile is idle?

Tags: java, android, sleep

How would you identify the user isn't using the mobile for 30 mins?

Using Jiro to see it's in horizontal position?

Is there any Android built-in flag for that?

Comment: Just a quick question - do you really need a gyro/accelero test? I can think of ways to see if the user has not touched the screen, will that meet your requirement.

Comment: No actual need for Gyro. I'm open to suggestions

Comment: What about checking if isScreenOn ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try working with events based on the display and when it has been enabled the last time.

Register a Broadcast Receiver for `ACTION_SCREEN_ON`, `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` and save the timestamp properly.

Please note, that the Screen-Events could be also fired by applications like WhatsApp if they automatically enable the display to show a new message. Due to this fact should you rather stick to [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT).

Here is some code:

**Android-Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".UserPresentBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class UserPresentBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

        /*Sent when the user is present after 
         * device wakes up (e.g when the keyguard is gone)
         * */
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){

        }
    }

}
```

Credits for the code go to [Chathura Wijesinghe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20225681/2393787)

Note: You will need a seperate thread (preferably a daemon-thread) to compare that timestamp with the current time.

Comment: so `USER_PRESENT` make my time-lapse counter 0. but is this event evokes on every user's touch?

Comment: This event is invoced only upon unlocking the phone.

Answer (score 5):

Listen for `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` to start timer, and clear timer only if you receive `ACTION_USER_PRESENT`, so you won't accidentally clear your timer when the screen is turned on by some apps.

For above method you can include the following when you start your timer. This way you take the auto-lock delay into account when the screen is off.

```
Settings.Secure.getLong(getContentResolver(), "lock_screen_lock_after_timeout", 5000);
```

Alternatively, you can use `KeyguardManager` to check if the lock screen is enabled every 1ms or so after screen is off.

In general, the idea is `lock screen --> idle; no lock screen --> not idle`

Comment: what can you say regarding the above comment? `Please note, that the Screen-Events could be also fired by applications like WhatsApp if they automatically enable the display to show a new message. Due to this fact should you rather stick to ACTION_USER_PRESENT.`

Comment: @EladBenda `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` checks lock screen status. Normally apps cannot unlock your phone unless itself is a lockscreen replacement or you've rooted your phone to yield access to that operation. If screen is unlocked then it's ok to assume that the user wants to interact with the phone.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the screen is turned off by calling [isScreenOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isScreenOn%28%29) method.

**Note:** This only can be used for 2.1 and above

Also you can also use [Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) to determine the status of your screen. Check this [link](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) for an example.

Reference: [isScreenOn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6691770/2451524) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6691784/2451524).

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on  how  you define "Idle" , screen off  need not mean  your  device is idle , the most common  secnario  been  if  there  is a  app  holding a  [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK)

1. ) One way to  tackle the  problem  would  what  many users have  suggested  here  to  listen to SCREEN_ON /OFF and ACTION_USER_PRESENT  in combination with keygaurd   or windowmanager api to detect  if user  input is  happening.

**Though  this  wont  work  if  you  have background   service  running  let  say  like   utorrent app.**

> Hence  if   you  want  to  use  screen on /off  option  I would
>   suggest  you also  check  for  active  wakelocks("adb shell dumpsys
>   power" to find  current active wakelocks held by the device )

There is one more way you can try though it may  a bit tedious  (depends  how accurately  you want to define  IDLE )

Use  Systrace([LINK](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html))  feature   exposed  by  android  to  track  cpu  frequency  and  host of other parameter  this way  you can monitor  various degrees of "idle-ness" as well.

there  are dedicated options  to track  CPU load  and cpu idle  events

> 1.) Android 4.3 onwards(api 18 and above) :use "idle"( CPU Idle) and
>   "load" ( CPU Load) as list category options.
>
> 2.) Android 4.2 and below (below  api 18) : use "-i, --cpu-idle"  to trace
>   cpu idle  events and  "-l, --cpu-load"  for  cpu load  percentage (
>   though  for  your need  cpu idle events  shall  do the  job ).

go  through the  link  for detailed  description, thanks.

Comment: `windowmanager api to detect if user input is happening.` how would you suggest?