# Does httpClient in AsyncTask need wakeLock?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am executing httpClient in AsyncTask but before this another AsyncTask is used to generate some data, which can take long time. If device gets sleep before executing httpClient, what would happen? Do I need wakeLock for httpClient requests?

Comment: I think the async task go also to sleep and wake up when the device wake up. If you want that your async task finish his work without a little rest you have to use wakeLock.

Comment: @JackTools.Net And why do you believe it?

Comment: How can a thread or an async task run when the cpu sleeps?

Comment: @JackTools.Net Please define *CPU sleeps*

Comment: @JackTools.Net I was wondering if device is sleeping (and so the asyncTask) then how and why am I getting debug messages ?

Comment: The CPU stop to work. Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html you need a partial_wake_lock to keep the cpu working.

Comment: @JackTools.Net I don't think they changed anything, because Android is a mobile OS, and without a running CPU it couldn't check for incoming calls and SMS ;) Don't confuse the power saving setting of a phone with the suspend/resume functionality in a laptop

Comment: Take a look at http://scape.cs.vt.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/ITJ12_Android_Energy-Aware.pdf Chapter three

Comment: @JackTools.Net Interesting paper, but can't see the point where the CPU is shut down. Quote?

Comment: When no wave locks 
are detected, the operating system places the hardware in deep sleep to 
save energy
[9] <- That is what I think too and this is what my app do without wake lock.

Comment: Take a look at [this][1] page. It would be helpful.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120185/android-sleep-standby-mode

Comment: @JackTools.Net I see. Also found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/EMagdkxWvpU). The problem is the behavior is device-dependent and context-sensitive (power supply plugged in) - above all, the root is in the core clock, whose stop suspends most scheduling. But the OP question is related to an AsyncTask either CPU or IO bound, so, even after reading your resources, I don't think Android goes to deep sleep while it's computing something or it's waiting for IO

Answer (score 0):

If the device go sleep, your activity `onPause()` is called. If you don't cancel/terminate the background task in some fancy way, nothing happens to it. `AsyncTask` are run in a separate thread than the main application one, so nothing can stop them. Ever.

I didn't understand your design: what's the purpose of two separate `AsyncTask`s? If gathering data to fill the HTTP request consumes time, you should use a single `AsyncTask` and do everything inside `doInBackground()`, to ensure no race condition happens. Otherwise you'd have to chain tasks, or fire the second one in the first one, and this doesn't sound right.

The HTTP client is just a socket library, is not a mythological beast :)

Comment: Even if I use single AsyncTask if its long running would I need wakeLock?

Comment: You never need a wakeLock, if you use one, two, three, four, a hundred tasks. [Demo project](http://pastebin.com/kaSjucR1) which sleeps ten seconds and then logs a line. Launch this Activity (requires 4.0+) and see if the log line is printed while the device screen is turned off

Comment: My Logs are printed too but HttpClient not working. Working perfectly when used wakelock.

Comment: @SohailAziz don't think it's a problem with WakeLock. Can you run the  [following code](http://pastebin.com/TUPgFDQ2) (requires 4.0+ and INTERNET permission)?

Comment: @Raffaelle change your demo projekt to write a line to your log every minute and run it for an hour or two to test it. If you get 120 Loglines after two hours then I belive that you don't need wake_lock.