# Service goes to standby when device sleeps - Android

Tags: android, android-wake-lock, sleep-mode, android-powermanager

Envrionment: Eclipse
Language: Java (Android)

I have a bit of a problem, which I didn't realise until I tested my application out on a device. I always thought that services would continuously be running in the background, even when the phone's sleeping. I found out that this is not the case, so, my question is that does the service start up again once you wake your device up? And if not, how would I cause the service to start-up again.

Would I be able to wake the phone every 5 minutes or so, just to run my service, which will last 30 seconds to 1 minute. And then make the phone sleep again?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am very new to Android programming and would really appreciate if someone would tell me how to use WakefulIntentService. 
I have a service that is searching for the user's GPS Location every so often, and when the phone goes to sleep, I want my service to still look for their location. How would I go about using the WakefulIntentService for this? And would I be able to use it in this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Sleep/Standby Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120185/android-sleep-standby-mode)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I used `AlarmManager`, I looked at `WakefulIntentService` and that gave me an idea on what to do.
Thanks again for the help everyone.

Comment: Why this is downvoted so hard? AlarmManager is worse than keeping lock on CPU??

Answer (score 11):

You need to hold the processor `lock` to keep your service running

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "TAG");
wl.acquire();
// When you are done
wl.release();
```

And if your service is using `Wi-Fi`, you need another lock as well

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiLock= wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "TAG");
wifiLock.acquire();

// When you are done
wifiLock.release();
```

Remember to add `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` in your manifest

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am quite a noob at Android development, as you probably have figured out, from my above question, but could you please elaborate what you mean by `lock`. Thanks for the speedy reply...

Comment: The above approach will kill the battery quickly.

Comment: The question is **not** about battery, and if you design you app *correctly* it should not affect

Comment: Thanks guys, @323go I know that the battery life will be drained quickly, but I don't need to be running the above code 24/7 it's only certain times in the day, which last up to a maximum of 15 minutes. Would that still affect badly? Also I will test it out and see how badly it drains, and if it kills it very quickly, I shall use a different approach. Thanks again guys...

Comment: @iTech, setting a wifi lock and a wake lock to keep the service running in the background is a bad idea, unless the service is actually doing something. Consider that the question wasn't about the battery because the asker didn't know the implications -- by ignoring those, you pointed him to the wrong answer. user - the correct answer is to look at a WakefulIntentService.

Comment: Thanks @323go, the service is doing something, it's looking for your GPS location or looking for Wi-Fi SSID's in range...

Comment: @323go using `lock` is definitely needed in so many cases and if you use it *correctly*, it should not affect the battery life! open android source code and the system apps developed by Google and you will find it is using `lock` a lot! saying "the correct answer is to look at a WakefulIntentService" as general statement is indeed incorrect

Comment: "it should not affect battery life" is a false statement. Of course it will ALWAYS affect battery life if used. The idea is to reduce the effect as much as possible. Further, please look at the question. It wasn't how to keep the service working, but how to wake it up after it was stopped.

Comment: ....using the device will "waste" battery life.  If "locks" are used when they are needed, and released when they are not, using them should be OK.  They're there for a reason.

Comment: dont worry about the battery....let the code do its task....above code works for 3G perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a service that is searching for the user's GPS Location every so often, and when the phone goes to sleep, I want my service to still look for their location. How would I go about using the WakefulIntentService for this? And would I be able to use it in this scenario.

`WakefulIntentService` is inappropriate here, as it is designed only to keep the device awake for a short period of time to do some work. It is not designed to keep the device awake for an indeterminate time, such as the time it takes to get a GPS fix.

I have [a `LocationPoller` project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) that handles your scenario a bit better.

> I am very new to Android programming

What you are trying to do is not a suitable project for somebody with your Android experience level, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help and opinions. I guess it's not suitable, but that's the way how I learn. I set myself a task to do. And see if I can accomplish that task. If I get stuck along the way, I learn via searching Google and asking questions here at StackOverflow. By the way, I found out another way, I used `AlarmManager`, I looked at your `WakefulIntentService` and that gave me an idea on what to do. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your service is doing exactly, but if it's down/uploading data to a server you might want to consider using a [Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).

Unless you need exact timing this is less of a burden on your system than AlarmManager.

I you are doing something else, you might want to look into the  [JobScheduler API](http://toastdroid.com/2015/02/21/how-to-use-androids-job-scheduler/).

Anyway if you really want to stick to AlarmManager just know that Inexact Repeating is already a lot better than Exact Repeating.

Comment: Thanks for a reply, however, this question was asked two years ago (by me) and already has an accepted answer (two years ago)
Please try to avoid reviving old threads, thanks ;)

Comment: Other people will still find this thread looking for an answer to a similar problem. That's why I replied. But other than that you are right.