# What actions can be performed when an android device is in sleep mode?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, intentfilter, wakelock

I am currently working on an application which requires a service running in the background to play music when the phone is in sleep mode.
I would like to know what are the actions that can be performed to trigger play music action while the device is in sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when your phone is in sleep mode it shuts down the CPU, when it is in sleep mode only thing which works is GSM or CDMA radio that is your incoming calls, SMSs, IP packets and AlarmManager...

After this answer you would think that, It even stop the services also if the phone is in sleep mode.

Then my Answer is, Yes. it does, since the CPU is powered down, all processes freeze in place. For more information you can visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120185/android-sleep-standby-mode).

Thanks to **@CommonsWare** for great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I would like to know one more thing. Does the device go into sleep mode when a headset is plugged in?

Comment: @mvp, No it does not go to sleep mode, even if you press lock key it does not directly sleep mode.