# Android Kiosk Mode without lockscreen

Tags: adb, kiosk-mode, cosu

I´m trying to configure a Android Single Use app. I´m using a Huawei P8 Lite with Android 6.0 and a Samsung Galaxy A3 2017 with Android 6.0. I´ve set the app to Device Owner and everything works well. I´ve deactivated Toast messages via adb and set the home button to the app. So everything works fine. When I start the app you can´t leave it anymore, even with a restart. But now there are 2 problems left. On the Samsung it works fine to deactivate Toast messages with the adb code

adb shell appops set android TOAST_WINDOW deny

but on the Huawei it does not work. It doesn´t show an error.

The second problem I got with the Samsung. When I restart the Huawei and press the "Home" Button I get directly into the app without having to swipe at the lockscreen. When I open the app at the Samsung it´s the same, but after a restart I always get into the lockscreen before entering the app. This is a little problem because it´s possible to open the dropdown menu with swiping down. The buttons there do not work but I want to get directly into the app when I press the Home or Power button.

So my Questions are:
- How to deactivate the toast messages on the Huawei?
- How to deactivate the whole lockscreen on the Samsung?

Anyone got an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bypass the lockscreen on the Samsung, you can try wake up the device by launching an activity as soon as the device starts, with the following flags

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

copied from [how to wakeup android phone from sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050164/how-to-wakeup-android-phone-from-sleep). Just make sure that you have chosen "None" as a screen lock type or called [setKeyguardDisabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setKeyguardDisabled(android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean)), which has the same effect.

To deactivate toast you need root privilege, so your device needs to be rooted and you need to do

```
adb root & adb shell appops set android TOAST_WINDOW deny
```

Comment: thank you i think this helps a lot! can you explain why the toast deactivation works fine on the samsung but not on the huawei?

Comment: Maybe the Huawei is not rooted? Or you didn't call `adb root`?

Comment: The Samsung isn´t rooted too but adb shell appops set android TOAST_WINDOW deny works fine while it doesn´t on the huawei.

Comment: Then maybe the `android` package is not the one showing the toast. You can try disabling toast for other system packages, you can get the list with `adb shell cmd package list packages -s -e` (or `adb shell pm list packages -s -e` on old versions for adb).