# Is Sleep Mode the same as Standby Mode

Tags: android

Google does not define the term "Sleep Mode" in their docs, but they do define [Standby Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120185/android-sleep-standby-mode) and [Doze Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120185/android-sleep-standby-mode). When people talk about "Sleep Mode" are they usually talking about "Standby Mode"? See

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_mode

Comment: I was just hoping for a technical definition of "sleep mode" in the Google Docs, but I only see "doze" and "standby".

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone has a better answer, I will assume `sleep mode` is ambiguous and can refer to the screen being off and/or the phone being in either `standby` or `doze`.